# Rendering jGallery as PartialView not working when using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I´m using [jGallery](http://jgallery.jakubkowalczyk.pl/) to render my images.  I show all my images on page load and that works very well using jGallery.  I render my gallery as a ***PartialView***.  I´m also using [Kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/upload/index.html) for my file uploader.  My goal is to use the uploader to add images to my collection and then upon success refresh my jGallery grid.

The problem I´m facing is, that, whenever file is uploaded, I call my controller to get all the images from database using ***AJAX***, but the ***jGallery*** doesn't render at all.  All it does is render the markup without any script working.

How can I use ***PartialView*** with ***AJAX***, and still use jGallery script within the ***PartialView***?  (I hope this question makes any sense)

**My Index.cshtml and my controller action:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Image> images = _imageModel.GetAllImages();

    return View(new ImageViewModel(images));
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
//stuff abbreviated
<div id="ImageSection">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("LoadImages", Model);
    }
</div>
//stuff abbreviated
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
          .Enable(true)
          .Name("files")
          .Async(a => a
            .Save("Save", "Image")
            .Remove("Remove", "Image")
            .AutoUpload(true)
          )
          .Events(e => e.Success("onImageUploadSuccess"))
          )
</div>
```

**My onImageUploadSuccess query and my controller action:**

```
function onImageUploadSuccess(e) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: 'Image/LoadImages/',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#ImageSection").html(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //TODO: error
    }
});
}
```

**Controller action**

```
public ActionResult LoadImages()
{
    IEnumerable<Image> images = _imageModel.GetAllImages();

    return PartialView(new ImageViewModel(images));
}
```

**LoadImages.cshtml**

```
@model WebPage.ViewModels.ImageViewModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div style="padding: 0px 0; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; height: auto;">
        <div id="gallery">
            @foreach (var cat in Model.Categories)
            {
                string cat1 = cat;
                <div class="album" data-jgallery-album-title="@cat1">
                    <h1>@cat1</h1>
                    @foreach (var image in Model.Images.Where(w => w.Category.Name.Equals(cat1)))
                    {
                        <a href="@Url.Action("GetImageData", "Image", new { id = image.Id })">
                            <img src="@Url.Action("GetImageData", "Image", new { id = image.Id })" alt="@image.Description"
                            data-jgallery-bg-color="@image.BackgrColor" data-jgallery-text-color="@image.TextColor" />
                        </a>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**This is onDocumentReady**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#gallery').jGallery({
    mode: 'standard', // [ full-screen, standard, slider ]
    width: '100%', // (only for standard or slider mode)
    height: '600px', // (only for standard or slider mode)
    autostartAtImage: 1,
    autostartAtAlbum: 1,
    canResize: true,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    textColor: '#fff',
    thumbnails: true,
    thumbnailsFullScreen: true,
    thumbType: 'image', // [ image | square | number ]
    thumbnailsPosition: 'top', // [ top | bottom | left | right ]
    reloadThumbnails: true, //Reload thumbnails when function jGallery() is called again for the same item
    thumbWidth: 100, //px
    thumbHeight: 100, //px
    thumbWidthOnFullScreen: 100, //px
    thumbHeightOnFullScreen: 100, //px
    canMinimalizeThumbnails: true,
    transition: 'moveToBottom_moveFromTop', // http://jgallery.jakubkowalczyk.pl/customize
    transitionWaveDirection: 'forward', // [ forward | backward ]
    transitionCols: 1,
    transitionRows: 5,
    showTimingFunction: 'linear', // [ linear | ease | ease-in | ease-out | ease-in-out | cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n) ]
    hideTimingFunction: 'linear', // [ linear | ease | ease-in | ease-out | ease-in-out | cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n) ]
    transitionDuration: '0.5s',
    zoomSize: 'original', // [ fit | original | fill ] (only for full-screen or standard mode)
    title: true,
    slideshow: true,
    slideshowAutostart: false,
    slideshowCanRandom: true,
    slideshowRandom: false,
    slideshowRandomAutostart: false,
    slideshowInterval: '8s',
    preloadAll: false,
    disabledOnIE8AndOlder: true,
    initGallery: function () {
    },
    showPhoto: function () {
    },
    beforeLoadPhoto: function () {
    },
    afterLoadPhoto: function () {
    },
    showGallery: function () {
    },
    closeGallery: function () {
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your event binding assumes existing dom objects at time of binding. All of your bindings against `$('#gallery')` happen before the element exists and are thus ignored.

You could try instead, to create a function encapsulating all your `$('#gallery')` bindings and call it on your success `Ajax` call.

```
function bindGallery(){
$('#gallery').jGallery({
    mode: 'standard', // [ full-screen, standard, slider ]
    width: '100%', // (only for standard or slider mode)
    height: '600px', // (only for standard or slider mode)
    autostartAtImage: 1,
    autostartAtAlbum: 1,
    canResize: true,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    textColor: '#fff',
    thumbnails: true,
    thumbnailsFullScreen: true,
    thumbType: 'image', // [ image | square | number ]
    thumbnailsPosition: 'top', // [ top | bottom | left | right ]
    reloadThumbnails: true, //Reload thumbnails when function jGallery() is called again for the same item
    thumbWidth: 100, //px
    thumbHeight: 100, //px
    thumbWidthOnFullScreen: 100, //px
    thumbHeightOnFullScreen: 100, //px
    canMinimalizeThumbnails: true,
    transition: 'moveToBottom_moveFromTop', // http://jgallery.jakubkowalczyk.pl/customize
    transitionWaveDirection: 'forward', // [ forward | backward ]
    transitionCols: 1,
    transitionRows: 5,
    showTimingFunction: 'linear', // [ linear | ease | ease-in | ease-out | ease-in-out | cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n) ]
    hideTimingFunction: 'linear', // [ linear | ease | ease-in | ease-out | ease-in-out | cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n) ]
    transitionDuration: '0.5s',
    zoomSize: 'original', // [ fit | original | fill ] (only for full-screen or standard mode)
    title: true,
    slideshow: true,
    slideshowAutostart: false,
    slideshowCanRandom: true,
    slideshowRandom: false,
    slideshowRandomAutostart: false,
    slideshowInterval: '8s',
    preloadAll: false,
    disabledOnIE8AndOlder: true,
    initGallery: function () {
    },
    showPhoto: function () {
    },
    beforeLoadPhoto: function () {
    },
    afterLoadPhoto: function () {
    },
    showGallery: function () {
    },
    closeGallery: function () {
    }
  });
};
```

and add to your Ajax Success:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#ImageSection").html(data);
    bindGallery();
},
```

Comment: I actually didn´t realize that the binding was happening before the element existed.  Thank you for your help.